# Is it possible in React to read data from text/properties file automatically and display it on browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For example I have `Demo.txt` file with content "version:1.0" and I want to display this on UI.
I have tried fileSystem methods but got the error `readFile/readSyncFile is not a function` on Firefox.Probably, fs is not appropriate approach to do this.

PS- I am avoiding to browse file at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Use this like this:

```
readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
```